# How to specify Javascript path when calling Javascript method from C# using Xamarin android?

Tags: javascript, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have this Xamarin Android project in which I need to call a Javascript method from C#. The name of the method is "drawMap". I have used the following technique to call the method.

```
webView.EvaluateJavascript(string.Format("mapDraw(" + ConvertToRadians(degree) + ")"), null);
```

But this MainActivity class is at the root of the project and Javascript class is inside Views-> test.js. How do I set the path to look for this method in that class?

Below code exists in the RazorView.cshtml file.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     function mapDraw(radValue) {
            var updatedPoint = mapImg.getMapCoordinates(currentPoint[0] + Math.sin(radValue), currentPoint[1] - Math.cos(radValue), false);
            console.log(currentPoint);
            console.log(updatedPoint);
            var line = new fabric.Line([currentPoint[0], currentPoint[1], currentPoint[0], currentPoint[1]], {
                stroke: 'red',
                originX: 'center',
                originY: 'center'
            });

            canvas.add(line);
            line.set({
                x2: updatedPoint[0],
                y2: updatedPoint[1]
            });
            canvas.renderAll();
            currentPoint = updatedPoint;
        }
 }
```

This drawMap is the method I have to call from C#

Answer (score 0):

You can call JS in WebView by `LoadUrl` method, first be sure you set Enable to true for `Settings.JavaScriptEnabled`.

```
WebView wv = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
wv.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
wv.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;

webview.LoadUrl("javascript:mapDraw(\"" + ConvertToRadians(degree) + "\")");
```

Comment: How can I refer to its path. Its currently residing in "Views" directory and the name of the file is RazorView.cshtml. I need to refer to the drawMap method in that.

Comment: What have is a Xamarin Web view Android project. The webView available in it doesn't have the Eval method. The Eval method is available in the Xamarin Forms WebView :(

Comment: Still it throws the error, 10-14 13:39:22.882 I/chromium(18455): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: mapDraw is not defined", source:  (1)

Comment: Are you sure you do it after load RazorView.cshtml into webview?

Comment: yeah :( I can see the method inside "page" object.  var model = new Model1() { Text = "Text goes here" };
            var template = new RazorView() { Model = model };
            var page = template.GenerateString();

Comment: Add this LoadUrl(js) to some button event and when you see page was load fire event. It have to work. I used it. Page must be finish loaded.